# Convert hex code to text c# hex string different the other page

Tags: c#

I am working on network conversion (unicode) code, but the results are not what I want.

For reference, this is what I want to achieve: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/

E.g.
Input "E5BC B5E6 9F8F E6A6 86", received "張柏榆" <-----this is what i need

But I use the following reference code

```
public static string ConvertStringToHex(String input, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
{
    Byte[] stringBytes = encoding.GetBytes(input);
    StringBuilder sbBytes = new StringBuilder(stringBytes.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in stringBytes)
    {
        sbBytes.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
    }
    return sbBytes.ToString();
}
```

I get hex string "355F CF67 8669"

It does not convert the hex code into "張柏榆".

```
public static string ConvertHexToString(String hexInput, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
{
    int numberChars = hexInput.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberChars; i += 2)
    {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexInput.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return encoding.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Why does that not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`

```
string temp = ConvertStringToHex("張柏榆", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string temp1 = ConvertHexToString(temp, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

You can use this. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: You should explain what you changed.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your function, and it did give an error while trying to convert. Weirdly, when I tried with the string "E5BCB5E69F8FE6A686" (your string without the spaces), it worked.

You could modify your code to replace out the spaces automatically, I also added a line to remove any "-" signs (in case they are included):

```
public static string ConvertHexToString(String hexInput, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
{
    hexInput = hexInput.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");      //Edited here to not declare a new string, suggested by Clonkex in comment
    int numberChars = hexInput.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberChars; i += 2)
    {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexInput.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return encoding.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Comment: No need to change the variable names, just leave the first parameter as `hexInput` and then do `hexInput = hexInput.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");`

Comment: Yep, I edited. By the way, I use rextester as well! Its so useful when you can't test code normally :)

Comment: I've never used it before, I just googled "online c# compiler". Online compilers are incredibly useful when you don't have a proper environment set up for compiling code but want to answer a stackoverflow question :P